# are these words commonly used？：很好 、极好 、非常好 、相当好 、特别好 、十分好、极其好

Tags: difference

I am wondering what the differences are between these and how they could be used (example sentences would be awesome!). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget about '好', you can replace it with any other adjective. Your question is about the difference between superlatives

很 = is; very

极 = very; extremely

非常 = very; extraordinarily

相当 = quite; very

特別 = very; especially

十分 = very (fully)

极其, 极之 (more colloquial) are the same as 極 (more literary)

Examples:

她的成绩很好 = her grade is good/ her grade is very good

她的成绩极好 = her grade is very good/ her grade is extremely good

她的成绩相当好 = her grade is quite good/ her grade is very good

她的成绩特别好 = her grade is very good/ her grade is especially good

她的成绩十分好 = her grade is very good

More examples:

他跑得很快 = he runs fast/ he runs very fast

他跑得极快 = he runs very fast/ he runs extremely fast

他跑得相当快 = he runs quite fast/ he runs very fast

他跑得特别快 = he runs very fast/ he runs especially fast

他跑得十分快 = he runs very fast

Answer (score 0):

1. `很`, `非常`, and `十分` are by far the most colloquial and rather interchangeable. Note, however, an adverb of degree is usually incorporated in some sentences *by default*  (e.g., compare `他很高` vs `?他高`; the former is more idiomatic). In these instances, 'very' has a weak semantic presence.
2. `極` and `極其` are fairly written. `極` may work better with simpler, monosyllabic adjectives, e.g. `極好的機會` ('a splendid opportunity'), `極高的風險` ('very high risk'). `極其` may work better with more complex, bisyllabic adjectives. So `極其好` doesn't sound right, but `極其嚴峻` ('extremely serious') and `極其危險` ('extremely dangerous') are fine.
3. `相當` is also fairly written. So it sounds weird if the answerer in sentence b. uses `相當` as 'very', because it is only a friendly, informal conversation. Compare the formality to sentence a.

   > a. 這家公司開出的條件相當誘人。 The offer of this company is very tempting.
   >
   > b. Q: 你喜歡這個娃娃嗎？ Do you like this doll? A: 我相當喜歡。 I like it very much.
4. `特別` means 'especially', which means there is implied comparison. This is absent in `很`. In sentence b., there is implied comparison with the listener's previous performance. In sentence c., there is implied comparison with people other than the listener themself.

   > a. 你這次考試的成績很好。 Your grades in this exam are (very) good.
   >
   > b. 你這次考試的成績特別好。 Your grades in this exam are especially good. (perhaps implying you did better than before)
   >
   > c. 你的成績特別好。 Your grades are especially good. (perhaps implying you did better than others)